# react native gifted chat- Can't see messages I send can only see messages received from user

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm new to react native gifted chat and whenever I send message and log in as the other user they can see my message, when I however log back in as myself I can't see the message I sent only the ones received how do i display both?

How can I make it so that I can see both messages I sent and messages I receive, also do i create a listener for firebase firestore to check if a new message has been received?

```
class MatchesChat extends Component {
    state = {
        messages: [],
      }

      componentDidMount(){

        this.getMessages()

      }

      getMessages = async () => {
        let items1 = []
        let items=[]

        try{
        const query = await db.collection('dogs').where('dogId', '==', this.props.dog.dogId).get()
        query.forEach(function(response) {
          items.push(response.data())
          })



         for(let i=0;i<items[0].messages.length;i++){
           if(items[0].messages[i].user._id===this.props.navigation.state.params.user.id){
             items1.push(items[0].messages[i])
           }
         }
          for(let i=0;i<items1.length;i++){
            items1[i].createdAt=items1[i].createdAt.toDate()
          }

          this.setState({
            messages: items1       
    })
  }
  catch{
    alert(e)
  }

  }

    onSend(messages = []){
        //this.props.dispatch(sendNotification(this.props.navigation.state.params.user.id, messages[0].user.name, messages[0].text))
        this.setState(previousState => ({
          messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
        }))

        let res = JSON.stringify(this.state.messages)
       console.log("gifted: "+res)


            try {
        console.log("inside try")

        db.collection('dogs').doc(this.props.dog.dogId).update({
          messages: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(messages[0])

      })

      db.collection('dogs').doc(this.props.navigation.state.params.user.id).update({
        messages: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(messages[0])

    })

    } 
            catch(e) {
              console.log("block dog error")
            alert(e)
            }




  }

    render(){

       let res = JSON.stringify(this.state.messages)
       //console.log("messy: "+res)
        return(
            <GiftedChat
            messages={this.state.messages}
            onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
            user={{
              _id: this.props.dog.dogId,
              name: this.props.dog.dogname,
              avatar: this.props.dog.photo
            }}
          />
        )
        }  
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({getDog,getDogs}, dispatch)
  }

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {

      dog: state.dog,
      cards: state.cards
    }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MatchesChat)
```